# Calculate new invoice date including weekends, excluding holidays

Tags: excel

I would like to calculate a new invoice date as follows:

```
Starting Date + 14 days 
Where days includes weekends, but excludes holidays.
```

How can I do this?

The WorkDays and Networkdays functions don't quite seem to meet my needs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

In the end I went for this:

```
Public Function GetCalendarDaysExHolidays(DateStart As Date, MaxDate As Date, NumDays As Integer) As Date
Dim i As Date
Dim DaysCounted As Integer
Dim Rng As Range

DaysCounted = 0

i = DateStart

Do While i < MaxDate

    Set Rng = Sheets("Bank holidays").Range("A1:A1000").Find(what:=Format(DateValue(i), "DD/MM/YYYY"), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        DaysCounted = DaysCounted + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1

    If (DaysCounted = NumDays) Then
        GetCalendarDaysExHolidays = i
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Exit Function
```

End Function

Comment: You asked explicitly for a formula, and your tags did not include excel-vba.

Comment: Yup I know, sorry I changed the spec.

Comment: So I voted you down. You are not answering your own question. Moreover, it seems that you changed the specs AFTER posting this answer.

Comment: I changed the question, to match exactly the method I went with... you know I don't get any rep for marking it as answered right? I'm sorry I've offended you.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of 'holidays' differs by country, company, year, etc., so there's no standard function that would fit your needs.  Here's an overly simplified version of my preferred method:

```
Function GetNetWorkDays(DateStart As Date, DateEnd As Date) As Integer
    Dim i As Date
    i = DateStart

    While i < DateEnd
        If i <> #01/01/1900# and _
           i <> #01/02/1900# Then _
            GetNetWorkDays = GetNetWorkDays + 1
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Exit Function
End Function
```

where #01/01/1900# and #01/02/1900# are your holidays of choice. In the long run, you'd want to move the date criteria into a table of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want a solution with formulas, not VBA.

Suppose you have:

```
 A4:A8 -> your holidays table
 A14   -> your start date
 A16   -> number of days to add
```

Generate the following aux structure:

```
 c3    -> put a zero
 c4    -> =IF(AND(A4-A$14>0,(A4-A$14)<=(A$16+SUM(C$3:C3))),1,0)
 c5:c8 -> Copy down from c4
```

So, to obtain the new date, type the following in the result cell:

```
 =A14+A16+SUM(C4:C8)
```

HTH!